Configuring Protege Default Relationships
I have a very small ontology in Protege containing just a few classes. Selecting a class in the class hierarchy pane shows several properties, including subClassOf and disjoinWith (see screenshot). These appear in the editor automatically. I would like to define my own object property, a sub-property of rdfs:subClassOf. Is there a way to configure Protege so that it also appears wherever rdfs:subClassOf appears? In other words, why does Protege show some properties and not others?
.
